# Add specific date as default datetime to DateTimeField in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model which already has multiple records.
I now need to add a DateTimeField while giving a specific date as default for all the existing records of the model

in my model, I'm trying to do:

```
import datetime

class some_model:
    **some fields here**
    setup_date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime(2020,1,1))
```

on running makemigrations and migrate I do not get any error but the field does not get added to the database

I've also tried with a callback function as follows

```
def default_datetime_for_my_class():
    return datetime.datetime(1900,1,1)

class some_model:
    **some fields here**
    setup_date = models.DateTimeField(default = default_datetime_for_my_class)
```

Comment: Can you add the text of the migrations file that makemigrations created for you and some detail on  your underlying db?

Comment: What do you mean by *"...does not get added to the database"*? Do you have some existing data in the table? Did you add any data after migration?

Comment: after `makemigrations` you need to run `migrate`

Comment: on `makemigrations` a new file migration file is created in the app. however when running `migrate` , the field does not get added to the database. 

in django_migration table, new record is created stating this migration file ran successfully but it does not create the new field is should have created in the table

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the app under the 'INSTALLED_APPS' field in 'settings.py'?. Also, make sure that you're able to access it from the admin page. Go in yourApp/admin.py and write

```
admin.site.register(yourModel)
```

Comment: the app is included in INSTALLED_APPS list and have been using this specific model as usual without any issues. Its just that i need to add this DateTimeField and ensure that the default value of this column for existing records is 2020-01-01